# Different margin size for Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The Firefox and Chrome margin-top size are different i attached the two browser images and my css code please give a feedback how to fix that issues.

Firefox ui:

[image]

Chrome ui:

[image]

CSS code:

```
.toparea-right .user-img > img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.90);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.90);
    transform: scale(0.90);
    vertical-align: inherit;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -395px;
    margin-top: -115px;
    width: 45px;
}
```

In chrome margin-top: -115px is working but in Firefox that going top but margin-top:-15px; it's working firefox.

Comment: add your working code like jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ajerad30/tLr7w0oy/1/#&togetherjs=sIiLaj59dJ

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet to reset browser defaults

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```