# Margin is rendering differently in Firefox and Edge

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

How to show I to come to different Margin on Firefox and Edge.

In Firefox,

[image: how to show on Firefox]

In Edge,

[image: How to show on Edge, Edge version 44]

I have the element aside for my right column to build,

```
aside  {
 grid-area: info;
 display: inline;
 margin: 1px;
 background-color: #d2f3c6;

}
```

this work for Firefox and these for Edge,

```
body > aside  {

    grid-area: info;
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: block;
    -ms-grid-column: 3;


    -ms-grid-row: 3;

   margin: 1px;
   background-color: #d2f3c6;
   margin-top: 60px;

}
```

My CSS for desktop:

```
body {
display: grid;
display: -ms-grid; 
background-color: #eaf6e5;
grid-row-gap: 5px;
grid-template:  

    "header header header" auto
    "nav nav nav" auto
    "main main gap1" 1em
    "main main werb" 11em 
    "main main gap2" 3em
    "main main info" 1fr
    "footer footer footer" auto / 8% 64% 28%;


   -ms-grid-columns: 8% 64% 28%;

   -ms-grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

Here are my meta elements:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

but how the screenshot to show Edge display different margin…in Firefox and Chrome all is gut, only the Problem is on Edge…the advertising is from google I have it without div, how to show it,

[image: how have add the code from Google]

I took a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53993384/9461831), but nothing changed following those instructions.

---

Version Microsoft Edge , 18 .

Firefox and Chrome all Display gut.

[My](https://codeshare.io/5eeBNb) html Code.

[My](https://codeshare.io/5NYy01) css Code.

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Edge and Firefox browser are you using? can you post the Enough code (include the html elements and related css style) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks for your answer!, I will now do it...